# No power to entire circuit after adding a single receptacle

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I was just adding a receptacle to one of my electric circuits. Once completed, I turned the circuit breaker “on”. No power on any of the receptacles and lights on that circuit. I checked every receptacle and fixture on that circuit for breakage or burnout. They all look ok. The only thing that I did not check is the circuit breaker. It is not tripped that means there is no short circuit. Is it possible that the circuit breaker is malfunctioning?

Comment: Turn the circuit breaker off and on again, making sure to push the handle as far as it will go in each direction.

Comment: A tripped breaker does NOT mean that the handle is in the off position.  On a tripped breaker, the handle only moves a faction away from the ON position.  Try pushing the circuit to the off position, then to the On.  If there is a shot, the breaker will trip immediately and move away from the ON position.  You could also have a GFCI breaker in an outlet in the circuit that has tripped.

Comment: Did you utilize the backstabs?  Re-check the outlet you installed. I doubt it's the breaker.

Comment: Is your new receptacle the first receptacle on the circuit?  If there is a bad connection, you won't get power to everything downstream.

Comment: No. It is not the first receptacle.

Comment: I even changed the new receptacle twice.

Comment: Wild guess, you botched the installation, created a dead short which had 2 effects: tripped the breaker and burned out a splice connection at the first receptacle.  Backstab connections do burn out under just such circumstances.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Just wanted to let you know that I solved the issue. It was a faulty breaker. So, I replaced the breaker and everything works fine.